# Regex in R: Return index of the last digit of the first instance of numeric characters in a string

Tags: r, regex, string

Following are sample outputs

```
Input_String                |   output_col1   |   output_col2
a-123/123 Lion's park       |   a-123/123     |   Lion's park
b/11-341 lion 34 park       |   b/11-341      |   lion 34 park
flat 701 sector 4 city x    |   flat 701      |   sector 4 city x
```

if the numbers are separated by alphabets, they need to be considered as different numbers and only the first incidence needs to be captured in `output_col1`, and if they are separated by punctuations they should be considered as one single number.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: https://regex101.com/r/EcJoXs/1?

Comment: @degant not really. I want to reproduce the result in `output_col1` and `output_col2`. 
The suggested code matches numbers separated by alphabets as well. which is not intended.

Comment: Aah, got it. How about https://regex101.com/r/EcJoXs/2? You then have 2 capturing groups (1 and 2) to extract the highlighted data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `str_split`

```
library(stringr)
df1[c("output_col1", "output_col2")] <- do.call(rbind, 
       str_split(df1$Input_string, "(?<=[0-9])\\s+(?=[A-Za-z])", n=2))
df1
#              Input_string output_col1     output_col2
#1    a-123/123 Lion's park   a-123/123     Lion's park
#2    b/11-341 lion 34 park    b/11-341    lion 34 park
#3 flat 701 sector 4 city x    flat 701 sector 4 city x
```

---

Or without using any external packages

```
df2 <- cbind(df1, read.csv(text=sub("([-/ ]\\d+)\\s+", "\\1,", 
    df1$Input_string), header = FALSE, col.names = c('output_col1',
          'output_col2'), stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
df2
#              Input_string output_col1     output_col2
#1    a-123/123 Lion's park   a-123/123     Lion's park
#2    b/11-341 lion 34 park    b/11-341    lion 34 park
#3 flat 701 sector 4 city x    flat 701 sector 4 city x
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Input_string = c("a-123/123 Lion's park", "b/11-341 lion 34 park", 
"flat 701 sector 4 city x")), .Names = "Input_string", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

`tidyr::separate` can make the new columns using a lookbehind and `extra = "merge"`:

```r
library(tidyr)

df <- structure(list(Input_String = c("a-123/123 Lion's park", "b/11-341 lion 34 park", 
    "flat 701 sector 4 city x"), output_col1 = c("a-123/123", "b/11-341", 
    "flat 701"), output_col2 = c("Lion's park", "lion 34 park", "sector 4 city x"
    )), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("Input_String", "output_col1", 
    "output_col2"), row.names = c(NA, -3L))

df %>% separate(Input_String,    # column to separate
                into = paste0('out', 1:2),    # new column names
                sep = '(?<=\\d)\\s',    # use lookbehind in separator
                extra = 'merge')    # merge extra splits into second column

#>        out1            out2 output_col1     output_col2
#> 1 a-123/123     Lion's park   a-123/123     Lion's park
#> 2  b/11-341    lion 34 park    b/11-341    lion 34 park
#> 3  flat 701 sector 4 city x    flat 701 sector 4 city x
```

Answer (score 0):

**1) gsubfn::read.pattern** This uses `read.pattern` and a regex with two capture groups, one for each column:

```
library(gsubfn)
Input <- c("a-123/123 Lion's park", "b/11-341 lion 34 park", "flat 701 sector 4 city x")

data.frame(Input, read.pattern(text = Input, pattern = "^(.*?\\d\\S+) (.*)$", quote = "",
  as.is = TRUE, col.names = c("col1", "col2")), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

giving:

```
                     Input      col1            col2
1    a-123/123 Lion's park a-123/123     Lion's park
2    b/11-341 lion 34 park  b/11-341    lion 34 park
3 flat 701 sector 4 city x  flat 701 sector 4 city x
```

**2) no packages**  Using the same input and regex as above:

```
pat <- "^(.*?\\d\\S+) (.*)$"
data.frame(Input, 
           col1 = sub(pat, "\\1", Input, perl = TRUE), 
           col2 = sub(pat, "\\2", Input, perl = TRUE),
           stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

giving the same output.